# How to get the spinner's id on the onItemSelected method?

Tags: java, android, spinner

My problem is : I want to have 3 different spinners, that displays the same type of object, and I want to be able to identify from which spinner I get the data, for example : 
In spinner 1, the user selected "potato"
In spinner 2, the user selected "tomato"
In spinner 3, the user selected "fries"

But I can only get "the user selected [...]", since I don't know how to tell from which spinner I got the data.

I was wondering if there was a way to do that on the  onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) method ?

Comment: can you provide your code so i can help you out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have set a common listener for all the spinners, so you can distinguish which spinner was selected by checking `parent.getId()`:

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (parent.getId()){
        case R.id.spinner1:
            //your code here
            break;
        case R.id.spinner2:
            //your code here
            break;
        case R.id.spinner3:
            //your code here
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The View view is most likely the spinner that made the selection.  If you set the .tag = 1 of each spinner to different numbers at the start of your program, then you will be able to look at what tag value is passed to the onItemSelected method:

```
if (view.tag == 1)...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private int mainSelectedItemId = 0, subSelectedItemId = 0;
private String mainSelectedItemStr, subSelectedItemStr;
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    if (adapterView.getId() == R.id.spiner_main) {
        mainSelectedItemId = position;
        mainSelectedItemStr = adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Log.e("zxzx1", "spiner_main:\n positionID: " + mainSelectedItemId + "\n SelectedItemStr: " + mainSelectedItemStr);
    } else if (adapterView.getId() == R.id.spiner_sub) {
        subSelectedItemId = position;
        subSelectedItemStr = adapterView.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Log.e("zxzx2", "spiner_sub:\n positionID: " + subSelectedItemId + "\n SelectedItemStr: " + subSelectedItemStr);
    }
}
```

result in logs:

```
2023-06-29 20:48:28.076 10257-10257 zxzx1  com.tech.appName E > spiner_main:
 positionID: 0
SelectedItemStr: Mens
2023-06-29 20:48:49.591 10257-10257 zxzx2  com.tech.appName E  spiner_sub: 
positionID: 2
SelectedItemStr: T.Shirt
```